# flex conditional data provider to tree on the basis of list selection

Tags: apache-flex

This is my XML data in a file named `nodesAndStuff.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <node label="One" />
    <node label="Two" />
    <node label="Three" />
    <node label="Four" />
    <node label="Five" />
    <node label="Six" />
    <node label="Seven" />
    <node label="Eight" />
    <node label="Nine" />
</root>
```

The component using this data source is an `XMLListCollection` which is bound to a spark `List` and the code for that is:

```
<s:Application name="Spark_List_dataProvider_XML_test"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
    initialize="init();">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void {
            xmlListColl.source = nodes.children();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="nodes" source="nodesAndStuff.xml" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List id="lst"
        labelField="@label"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl" />
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Now I have added my tree just below the list and I have saved counting from 10 to 19 in `one.xml`, 20 to 29 in `two.xml` and so on in different XML file. I have no clue how to connect the XML containing counting from 10 to 19 as the single node in tree at the selection of label one in list.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.  Please don't use a translator and try to find someone that can translate for you.

Comment: perhaps i have written it wrong its how to change the data provider of the tree with the selection of list.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways to do what you want to do.  Keeping in the spirit of your example, I have modified it to do what I **think** you are asking:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void {
            processXML(one);
        }

        private function processXML(nodes:XML):void {
            xmlListColl.removeAll();
            xmlListColl.source = nodes.children();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="one" source="one.xml" />
    <fx:XML id="two" source="two.xml" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List id="lst"
        labelField="@label"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl" />
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>

<s:Button label="Change" click="processXML(two)" />
```

Comment: with respect sir i thank you for your concern over the issue but i guess i have not been able to present my question my question was when i select anode ion list at that time my tree control which is hidden should be visible and should be able to get the value on dynamic from the xml file as per the name in nameAndstuff.xml like if i select index 0 i.e "one" as per the node label then my one.xml should be the dataprovider source for the tree control,And if nodal index 1 i.e is two is selected then the source change to Two.xml.Hope to hear from you soon.thanks

Comment: Sorry, @nitin, I really don't understand what you are asking.  What problem are you running into?  What have you tried?  Your example code didn't have anything about a tree control, so it is not clear what your actual problem is.